# Dash pattern matching callbacks: MATCH in Input but not in Output

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I want to use Dash pattern matching callbacks' `MATCH` as an `Input`, without needing to `Output` to the same `MATCH`. Imagine I generate a long, random list of items, from which a user may select any number of items. As they select each item, I want to append that item to a list in real time. It's a long list of 1,000+ items, so I don't want to see the whole `ALL` list, just the one they've selected in real time, so I can do a fast, efficient callback.

Something like the following:

```py
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, State, MATCH, ALL
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

# HTML table header and rows
header = html.Thead(html.Tr([html.Th("Add Part"), html.Th("Description")]))
rows = html.Tbody(
    [
        html.Tr(
            [
                html.Td(
                    dbc.Button(
                        "Add",
                        id={"type": "part_add", "index": i},
                        n_clicks=0,
                    ),
                ),
                html.Td(f"Index {i}"),
            ]
        )
        for i in range(1000)
    ]
)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Store(id="my_list", storage_type="local", data=[]),
    dbc.Table(
        [header, rows],
        bordered=True,
        striped=True,
    )
])


@app.callback(
    Output("my_list", "data"),
    Input({"type": "part_add", "index": MATCH}, "id"),
    State("my_list", "data"),
)
def match_callback_test(
    part_add_id,
    my_list_data 
):
    return my_list_data.append(part_add_id)
```

Is the above possible, with a different pattern? I get a JavaScript console error if I run the above.

Comment: I'm pretty sure match needs to be in both input and output to work. You could try using all and then filtering the input values, say based on the timestamp for when they were updated. However, since you have such a large list, as you mention, that could be lengthy. It might be worth looking at another way to approach this.

Comment: I think I will make a new feature request, or maybe even figure it out myself and make a pull request. This would be so efficient and effective if only we didn't have to have `MATCH` in the output as well

Answer (score 4):

If MATCH is used, MATCH also needs to be on all of the Outputs. Just use ALL instead and check which id was triggered with ctx. Working example:

```
from dash import (
Dash,
dcc,
html,
Input,
Output,
State,
MATCH,
ALL,
ctx,
exceptions,
no_update,
)
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

# HTML table header and rows
header = html.Thead(html.Tr([html.Th("Add Part"), html.Th("Description")]))
rows = html.Tbody(
    [
        html.Tr(
            [
                html.Td(
                    dbc.Button("Add", id={"type": "part_add", "index": i}, n_clicks=0,),
                ),
                html.Td(f"Index {i}"),
            ]
        )
        for i in range(10)
    ]
)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Store(id="my_list", storage_type="local", data=[]),
        dbc.Table([header, rows], bordered=True, striped=True,),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("my_list", "data"),
    Input({"type": "part_add", "index": ALL}, "n_clicks"),
    State("my_list", "data"),
)
def match_callback_test(part_add_id, my_list_data):

    trigger = ctx.triggered_id
    if trigger:
        my_list_data.append(trigger["index"])
        return my_list_data
    return no_update


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```